# Once the question is deleted, the OP box in which the name sits disappears

Tags: bug, status-declined

You can see that the name of OP is placed in a special box...

> [image]

But once deleted, the blue box is gone:

> [image]

Comment: OH NO!  DEAR GOD NO!  SAY IT ISN'T SO!!!!

Comment: How is this even remotely an issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see why this is necessary.

The deleted question is somewhat 'grayed out', and I don't think it needs the emphasis on the user name box once deleted.

I would just keep it like this. I never ever 'missed' the box when the question was deleted.